# How to print a object html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that has a couple of clone items. Im trying to print it out but I keep getitng "[object HTMLDivElement]" instead of the actual html

```
$.each(theGood, function() {
        $('#work .slider').wrap(function(){
                $('#work .slider').prepend('<div class="group">'+this+'</div>');
            });
        });
}
```

Here's the code I'm using. I tried doing a for loop with theGood[i} but no luck

Comment: try `$('#work .slider').prepend('<div class="group">'+this.innerHTML+'</div>')`.

Comment: `$.each(theGood, function(el)` and than use `el` instead of `this` or `el.html()` if `theGood` is a selector. If, of course, you want to output `theGood`

Comment: instead of `this.innerHTML` you can use `$("<p/>").text(this.innerHTML).html()` if you wanna print the html.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is a simple set of name-value properties (an associative array for all intents/purposes), the for loop should work just fine for your purposes:

```
var memo = "";
for(var key in myFirstObject) {
    // Use comma-delimited list for stringified version of object:
    memo += (memo.length > 0 ? ", " : "") + key + ": " + myFirstObject[key];
}
$("#work .slider").prepend('<div class="group">' + memo + '</div>');
```

If this doesn't address your concerns, perhaps it would help to have more information about what you're trying to accomplish, as well as the nature of the object (e.g. the results from a `console.log(this)` in your javascript console).